# How to perform Patch

Tags: angular13

I have a login form, which I have implemented using reactive forms. I have created a static table also, once the login form is filled and clicked the save button, all the values will be populated in to that table. I need to implement an edit button in that table. Once the edit button got clicked all the table values should be populated back to the login form. How should I implement this in Angular 13

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Find the userId that you need to update (create an edid button on each table item which gives you the id).
2. If its an array your can use find Index
3. Now update your array index to the given value.

// Login Table List
let loginList = [
    { userID: 1, userName: 'Alex' },
    { userID: 2, userName: 'Bob' },
    { userID: 3, userName: 'Soni' }
]

// Update function
const update = (userID, userName) => {
    let index = loginList.findIndex((userName, index) => userName.userID === userID);
    loginList[index] = { userID: userID, userName: userName }
}

update(1, 'George');
console.log(loginList);
/*
    // Updated Login List
    [
        { userID: 1, userName: 'Geroge' },
        { userID: 2, userName: 'Bob' },
        { userID: 3, userName: 'Soni' }
    ]
*/
```